# Accessing array object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

As I dig deeper on javascript data structures. I am stuck on figuring out how to add properties to objects inside arrays. This is my code below

```
const reviews = [
    {name: "Daniela", rating: 5, feedback:"Beautiful atmosphere and wonderful vegan options!"},
    {name: "Jack", rating: 3, feedback:"A little too hipster for my taste, but the burger was decent, if overpriced"},
    {name: "Miranda", rating: 4, feedback:"fun trivia and cool vibes"},
    {name: "Wen", rating: 4.5, feedback:"I don't leave my house often, but when I do, it's for this place. Highly reccomend."},
    {name: "Brett", rating: 3, feedback: "great selection of snacks and a nice cafe area to get work done during the day."},
    {name: "Julius", rating: 2, feedback: "I was largely unimpressed by this venue. Nothing special on the menu and too expensive. The atmosphere is polarizing, and not for me, but I think some would like it." },
    {name: "Lauren", rating: 4, feedback: "Absolutely love that they have karaoke Fridays! Food and drink selection is okay."},
    {name: "Reyna", rating: 3.5, feedback: ""},
]
```

what I am trying to do here is to re-assign the `feedback` property for `name: "Reyna`

I have tried something like

```
reviews.push({
    name: 'Reyna',
    rating: 3.5,
    feedback: 'This place was okay'
  }
)
```

I am really stuck and trying so hard to figure out what it is that I am doing wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this.

You don't have to push the new object to the array, but you want to update the existing object.

So, the first task is to find the object.
To do so, You can use Array.find, or Lodash library to find, or if you know the element index, then you can directly access it like array[index].

```js
const reviews = [
    {name: "Daniela", rating: 5, feedback:"Beautiful atmosphere and wonderful vegan options!"},
    {name: "Jack", rating: 3, feedback:"A little too hipster for my taste, but the burger was decent, if overpriced"},
    {name: "Miranda", rating: 4, feedback:"fun trivia and cool vibes"},
    {name: "Wen", rating: 4.5, feedback:"I don't leave my house often, but when I do, it's for this place. Highly reccomend."},
    {name: "Brett", rating: 3, feedback: "great selection of snacks and a nice cafe area to get work done during the day."},
    {name: "Julius", rating: 2, feedback: "I was largely unimpressed by this venue. Nothing special on the menu and too expensive. The atmosphere is polarizing, and not for me, but I think some would like it." },
    {name: "Lauren", rating: 4, feedback: "Absolutely love that they have karaoke Fridays! Food and drink selection is okay."},
    {name: "Reyna", rating: 3.5, feedback: ""},
]

const myObj = reviews[7];
console.log('array[index]: ', myObj);

const myObj2 = reviews.find(x => x.name == "Reyna");
console.log('Array.find: ', myObj2);

myObj.feedback = 'whatever';

console.log(reviews);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This helped out

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to find your object and then you can modify it.

```js
const reynaReview = reviews.find(review => review.name === 'Reyna');
reynaReview.feedback = 'New Feedback';
```